numerical integration quadrature rule Radau formula
Consider a numerical integration rule of the form $\int_{0}^{1} f(t)dt \approx af(0)+bf(c)$
a)Find a,b,c such that this quadrature rule has highest order of precision.
b)The quadrature rule above has an erro0r formula of the form $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt= af(0)+bf(c)+Df^{r+1}({\epsilon})$ $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. Determine the constants $D$ and $r$.
My attempt was I put $f(t)=1$ and $f(t)=t$ inside the integral and found a rule like $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt\approx \frac{1}{4}f(0)+\frac{3}{4}f(\frac{2}{3})$. However since this is arbitrary quadrature rule I do not know how to compute error. Can someone help me? I know the error in Gaussian quadrature is $\frac{f^{4}(\epsilon)}{(4!)}\int_{0}^{1}(x-0)^{2}(x-\frac{2}{3})^{2}$. However this is not Gaussian quadrature so I do not know how to compute error! I a sorry I had a type mistake in previous one. I think the error must be $\int_{0}^{1}f[0,\frac{2}{3},t](t-0)(t-\frac{2}{3})dt$ by using Theorem on Error in Newton Interpolation.I just used
$f(t)=f(0)+f[0,\frac{2}{3}]t+f[0,\frac{2}{3},t](t-0)(t-\frac{2}{3})$
The integral of last term must be error. Is there a point I am missing?

I think error must be $\int_{0}^{1} f0,\frac{2}{3},t(t-\frac{2}{3})$ by using Theorem on Error in Newton Interpolation  in the book Cheney Numerical Analysis but the answer below contradicts with it why is it so?

Yes, that gives also a valid error formula, but not of the maximal error order. And it becomes more complicated to apply the mean value formula. You get a similar situation when exploring the Simpson rule.

Okay I get it I am doing with my error formula and error is being 0. Thank you for your help.

Remember that in the mean-value formula the weight function that remains inside the integral has to be everywhere positive. One could split the integral at $c$ to get a composite error term.

Careful application of partial integration leads to a weight function $t^2(1-t)$ in the new error term, which is non-negative over the interval.

This quadrature rule is based on the interpolation formula best written in Newton form for the nodes $0,c,c,t$,
\begin{align}
h(x)&=f(0)+f[0,c]\,x+f[0,c,c]\,x(x-c)+f[0,c,c,t]\,x(x-c)^2\\
\implies
f(t)=h(t)&=f(0)+f[0,c]\,t+f[0,c,c]\,t(t-c)+f[0,c,c,t]\,t(t-c)^2.
\end{align}
The last term becomes the error term under integration. $c$ is selected in such a way that the coefficient of $f'(c)$ in the third term becomes zero.
Integration gives
$$
\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt=f(0)+\frac12f[0,c]+\frac16f[0,c,c](2-3c)+\frac1{12}f[0,c,c,\tau](3-8c+6c^2)
$$
To remove $f'(c)$ set $c=\frac23$, then apply that $f[0,c,c,\tau]=\frac16f^{(3)}(\xi)$ to get
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt&=f(0)+\frac12\frac{f(\frac23)-f(0)}{\frac23}+\frac1{12\cdot 6\cdot 3}f^{(3)}(\xi)(9-16+8)\\
&=\frac14f(0)+\frac34f(\tfrac23)+\frac1{216}f^{(3)}(\xi)
\end{align}

How did you derive that rule?What was your first attempt when you looked at the question?Which steps you passed and how did you arrive that conclusion?

If a node is variable you can include the derivative at this node in a Hermite interpolation formula and arrange the node in such a way that the coefficient of the derivative vanishes. I wrote the Hermite interpolation as Newton interpolation with repeated roots.

If all nodes are variable one gets Gauß methods, if the first node is fixed to 0 or the last fixed to 1 you get Gauß-Lobatto rules that are the basis for the Radau methods for ODE, or so I understood.

This is not exactly Hermite Interpolation formula somehow different.You should start like $f(t)=f(0)+f0,0+f0,0,t^{2}+\ldots$

It is not Hermite with uniform differentiation orders, it is mixed. In my experience formulas with variable orders of differentiation are also called Hermite if any derivative at all is used.

why is the last term error?. I could not get the error point here well?

I do not also get you because c must be fixed and $\frac{2}{3}$.$f'(\frac{2}{3})$ is either $0$ or not. We can not know it

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I do not understand why error is not the integral of $f0,\frac{2}{3},t(t-\frac{2}{3}) $considering Theorem on Error in Newton Interpolation
